# drop down list get text of NON selected items

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have *multiple dropdown lists* in the same container that have an "any" option as its first item. I'm looking to get the text of a single option that is selected, OR if "any" is selected (value = 0), get an array of the REST OF the options in that list (but not the "any" option). serialize won't work of course because I'm looking for the non-selected options on some lists.

in my simple testing, the following worked for getting the text of the non-selected option texts in a single select:

```
var opts = $('select > option:not(:selected)').map(function() { return this.text; }).get();
```

but when I translated that to support as many selects as in my container (an unknown number) I ran into trouble. the map( .. ).get() / array concat is the most obvious way to me, looping/pushing seems messy (even if it's only hiding the same procedure inside jquery)

```
    var val = [];
    jQuery("select :selected", "#container").each(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == 0) { // "any"
            // _val.concat($(this).siblings().map(function() {return this.text; }).get()); // didn't work, even though siblings matches everything OTHER THAN the selected item
            _val.concat($('option:not(:selected)', $(this).parent()).map(function() { return this.text; }).get()); // didn't work either, even though this is all the options not selected mapped to an array
            //for (var i=0;i<$(this).siblings().length-1;i++) _val.push($(this).siblings().get(i).text()); // no; even though it is a <HTMLOptionElement>; ignore the potential bug in i if you spot it, it doesn't affect me!
        } else {
            _val.push(this.text); //$(this).text());
        }
    });
    _val.push(jQuery("input","#container").val());
    alert(_val.join(" ").toLowerCase()); // all my drop downs + my fields
```

as usual this is going to be some dumb little thing that's too obvious for me to work out (and it's late at night here).

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your script to:

```
var val = [];

jQuery("select", "#container").each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == 0) {
        val.push($(this).find('option:not(:selected)').map(function() {
            return this.text;
        }).get());
    } else {
        val.push($(this).find('option:selected').map(function() {
            return this.text;
        }).get());
    }
});

alert(val.join(", ").toLowerCase());
```

See this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mTaVH/1/) to check if it does what you expect.

Comment: Oh, I was trying to concat the array after map(..).get() when I could have just been push()ing it. Also noted the initial selector change, and that your fiddle used select multiple, which I do not want - but that's still ok. Thanks for the assist, it all makes sense now!

Comment: ooh, except that push() pushes the string of that array, not the elemenets to an array. I think this is because val is a javascript array and get() is returning a jquery object array, which isn't a real array. I tried transforming it using `val.push($.makeArray($this.find(...` but that didn't work (push OR concat, but using `$.mergeArray(val, $(this).find(...` is fine. final function in my own answer below.

Answer (score 0):

here's what I came up with which is a solution for me:

```
    var _val = [];
    jQuery("select", "#container").each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == 0) {
            jQuery.merge(_val, $(this).find('option:not(:selected)').map(function() { return this.text.toLowerCase(); }).get());
        } else {
            _val.push($(this).find('option:selected').map(function() { return this.text.toLowerCase(); }).get());
        }
    });
    _val.push(jQuery("input","#container").val().toLowerCase());
```